# jquery validation engine is validating inputs on search button click also

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

While i am using jquery validation engine it is validating inputs on search button click also can anyone please help me

i tried by putting causes validation=false also.

i need to validate only for save click

following is validationengine.js file

```
 (function($){
        $.fn.validationEngineLanguage = function(){
        };
        $.validationEngineLanguage = {
            newLang: function(){
                $.validationEngineLanguage.allRules = {
                    "required": { // Add your regex rules here, you can take telephone as an example
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* This field is required",
                        "alertTextCheckboxMultiple": "* Please select an option",
                        "alertTextCheckboxe": "* This checkbox is required",
                        "alertTextDateRange": "* Both date range fields are required"
                    },
                    "dateRange": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Invalid ",
                        "alertText2": "Date Range"
                    },
                    "dateTimeRange": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Invalid ",
                        "alertText2": "Date Time Range"
                    },
                    "minSize": {
                        "regex": "none",

                        "alertText": "* Minimum ",
                        "alertText2": " characters allowed"
                    },
                    "maxSize": {
                        "regex": "none",

                        "alertText": "* Maximum ",
                        "alertText2": " characters allowed"
                    },
                    "groupRequired": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* You must fill one of the following fields"
                    },
                    "min": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Minimum value is "
                    },
                    "max": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Maximum value is "
                    },
                    "past": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Date prior to "
                    },
                    "future": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Date past "
                    },  
                    "maxCheckbox": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Maximum ",
                        "alertText2": " options allowed"
                    },
                    "minCheckbox": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Please select ",
                        "alertText2": " options"
                    },
                    "equals": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Fields do not match"
                    },
                    "creditCard": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Invalid credit card number"
                    },
                    "phone": {
                        // credit: jquery.h5validate.js / orefalo
                        "regex": /^([\+][0-9]{1,3}[ \.\-])?([\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\)])?([0-9 \.\-\/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid phone number"
                    },
                    "email": {
                        // Shamelessly lifted from Scott Gonzalez via the Bassistance Validation plugin http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                        "regex": /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid email address"
                    },
                    "integer": {
                        "regex": /^[\-\+]?\d+$/,
                        "alertText": "* Not a valid integer"
                    },
                    "number": {
                        // Number, including positive, negative, and floating decimal. credit: orefalo
                        "regex": /^[\-\+]?(([0-9]+)([\.,]([0-9]+))?|([\.,]([0-9]+))?)$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid floating decimal number"
                    },
                    "date": {
                        "regex": /^\d{4}[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid date, must be in YYYY-MM-DD format"
                    },
                    "ipv4": {
                        "regex": /^((([01]?[0-9]{1,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))[.]){3}(([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid IP address"
                    },
                    "url": {
                        "regex": /^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid URL"
                    },
                    "onlyNumberSp": {
                        "regex": /^[0-9\ ]+$/,
                        "alertText": "* Numbers only"
                    },
                    "onlyLetterSp": {
                        "regex": /^[a-zA-Z\ \']+$/,
                        "alertText": "* Letters only"
                    },
                    "onlyLetterNumber": {
                        "regex": /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/,
                        "alertText": "* No special characters allowed"
                    },
                    // --- CUSTOM RULES -- Those are specific to the demos, they can be removed or changed to your likings
                    "ajaxUserCall": {
                        "url": "ajaxValidateFieldUser",
                        // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
                        "extraData": "name=eric",
                        "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
                        "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                    },
                    "ajaxUserCallPhp": {
                        "url": "phpajax/ajaxValidateFieldUser.php",
                        // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
                        "extraData": "name=eric",
                        // if you provide an "alertTextOk", it will show as a green prompt when the field validates
                        "alertTextOk": "* This username is available",
                        "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
                        "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                    },
                    "ajaxNameCall": {
                        // remote json service location
                        "url": "ajaxValidateFieldName",
                        // error
                        "alertText": "* This name is already taken",
                        // if you provide an "alertTextOk", it will show as a green prompt when the field validates
                        "alertTextOk": "* This name is available",
                        // speaks by itself
                        "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                    },
                     "ajaxNameCallPhp": {
                            // remote json service location
                            "url": "phpajax/ajaxValidateFieldName.php",
                            // error
                            "alertText": "* This name is already taken",
                            // speaks by itself
                            "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                        },
                    "validate2fields": {
                        "alertText": "* Please input HELLO"
                    },
                    //tls warning:homegrown not fielded 
                    "dateFormat":{
                        "regex": /^\d{4}[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$|^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-)31)|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-)(?:29|30)))(\/|-)(?:[1-9]\d\d\d|\d[1-9]\d\d|\d\d[1-9]\d|\d\d\d[1-9])$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))(\/|-)(?:[1-9]\d\d\d|\d[1-9]\d\d|\d\d[1-9]\d|\d\d\d[1-9])$|^(0?2(\/|-)29)(\/|-)(?:(?:0[48]00|[13579][26]00|[2468][048]00)|(?:\d\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid Date"
                    },
                    //tls warning:homegrown not fielded 
                    "dateTimeFormat": {
                        "regex": /^\d{4}[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\s+(1[012]|0?[1-9]){1}:(0?[1-5]|[0-6][0-9]){1}:(0?[0-6]|[0-6][0-9]){1}\s+(am|pm|AM|PM){1}$|^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-)31)|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-)(?:29|30)))(\/|-)(?:[1-9]\d\d\d|\d[1-9]\d\d|\d\d[1-9]\d|\d\d\d[1-9])$|^((1[012]|0?[1-9]){1}\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]){1}\/\d{2,4}\s+(1[012]|0?[1-9]){1}:(0?[1-5]|[0-6][0-9]){1}:(0?[0-6]|[0-6][0-9]){1}\s+(am|pm|AM|PM){1})$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid Date or Date Format",
                        "alertText2": "Expected Format: ",
                        "alertText3": "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM|PM or ", 
                        "alertText4": "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM|PM"
                    }
                };

            }
        };

        $.validationEngineLanguage.newLang();

    })(jQuery);
```

my aspx page code :

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                        //jQuery("#form1").validationEngine();
                        jQuery("#frmMaster").validationEngine();
                    });
                    </script>




                    </script>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
                   <fieldset id="feild">

                <legend>Requirement Form</legend>
                <table id="RequirementForm">
                <tr>
                <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblreqid" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblReqcode" runat="server" Text="Requirement Code" ></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtReqCode" runat="server"  CssClass="validate[required]" Width="200" ></asp:TextBox><asp:Label ID="lblReqcodeError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"   ></asp:Label></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblReqSummary" runat="server" Text="Requirement Summary" ></asp:Label>

                </td>
                <td>




                <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtReqSummary" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" TextMode="MultiLine">--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtreqsummary" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="5" runat="server"  
                  CssClass="validate[required,maxSize[250]]"  Width="200"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblReqDescription" runat="server" Text="Requirement Description" ></asp:Label></td>
                <td><FTB:FreeTextBox ID="RichTextBoxDescription" runat="server" EnableToolbars="true" 
                        ClientIDMode="AutoID" FormatHtmlTagsToXhtml="False" Height="250px" 
                        ToolbarLayout="FontFacesMenu,FontSizesMenu,FontForeColorsMenu,Bold,Italic,Underline,Strikethrough;JustifyLeft,JustifyRight,JustifyCenter,JustifyFull; BulletedList,NumberedList,Indent,Outdent;CreateLink,Unlink" 
                        Width="700px"  >
                </FTB:FreeTextBox></td>
                <%--<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtReqDescription" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" TextMode="MultiLine"   ></asp:TextBox></td>--%>
                </tr>

                <tr>

                 <td></td>
                <td align="left">
                <asp:Button ID="btnsave" Text="Save" runat="server"   CssClass="buttonreq" 
                        onclick="btnsave_Click"  OnClientClick="validate()"/> 

                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server"  class="buttonreq" 
                        onclick="btnCancel_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
               </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

               <td></td>
                <td align="left">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" runat="server"  style="margin:20 20"  
                        class="buttonreq" onclick="btnSearch_Click" CausesValidation="false" />

                <asp:Button ID="btnaddnewreq" Text="AddNewRequirement" runat="server" 
                        style="margin:20 20"  class="buttonreq" onclick="btnaddnewreq_Click"/>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <label id="lblerrors" style="width: 200px; color: red; border: none; font-size: 11px; font-style: italic"></label>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                </fieldset>

                        <fieldset  id="feild">

                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdRequirements" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
                        AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="grdRequirements_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        onrowdeleting="GrdRequirementsOnRowDeleting"
                        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
                        >
                <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RequirementID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblreqid" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("RequirementID") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RequirementCode">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblreqcode" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("RequirementCode") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RequirementSummary">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblreqsummary" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("RequirementSummary") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RequirementDescription"   >

                <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:Label ID="lblreqdesc" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("RequirementDescription") %>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
                </fieldset>


                </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use validation group wherever you need the validations to be there and on search button, i guess you don't need the validation, so don't use validation group there. Try searching about validation group and you'll get to know about the problem.